# can Gtk+ coexists with QApplication?

Tags: qt, gtk, swi-prolog

I'm running in troubles when attempting to run Gtk+ from a Qt application.

To clarify the context, I wrote (together with Jan Wielemaker) some Qt stuff 
for a portable [SWI-Prolog console](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-swipl-win).

It turned out to be a bit complicated, mainly because SWI-Prolog has its own thread management, and I had the requirement that was possible to instantiate multiple consoles, that *could* run their own thread... of course, the GUI had to be syncronized. Maybe I didn't took the better path to implementation, that - now I speculate - could be using virtual tty (forkpty and friends)...

Recently, an interesting pack has been released, [PLGI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=plgi), that enables building GObject based application.

It works great when started from swipl executable, but crashes when running from swipl-win.

Minimal example (requires PLGI, clearly, that in turn requires at least SWI-Prolog ver. 7.3, so perform the pack installation with `?- pack_install(plgi).` )

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <SWI-cpp.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    PlEngine e(argc, argv);

    QTimer::singleShot(5000, []() {
        printf("inside\n");
        int rc = PlCall("consult('/home/carlo/lib/swipl/pack/plgi/examples/00-simple-example')");
        printf("result %d\n", rc);
    });
    printf("after\n");

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And the process output:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.6-17-g243e698-DIRTY)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).


(use_plgi:2644): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'

(use_plgi:2644): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(use_plgi:2644): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

Of course, a Qt console application works:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <SWI-cpp.h>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    PlEngine e(argc, argv);

    printf("before\n");
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, []() {
        printf("inside\n");
        int rc = PlCall("consult('/home/carlo/lib/swipl/pack/plgi/examples/00-simple-example')");
        printf("result %d\n", rc);
    });
    printf("after\n");

    return a.exec();
}
```

From what I read about the error

```
(use_plgi:2644): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'
```

seems that the *message queue* cannot work, I've been unable to track down the problem. Any hint available ?

Comment: Since this is on a Unix system, Qt's event loop probably already registers everything needed for GTK interoperation, and then some prolog package tries to do the same in the same process. That won't work.

Comment: then you suggest to modify PLGI initialization ? thanks, I will look there.

Comment: I'm not sure. I think that what you're trying to do has no chance of working in general: PLGI thinks that it has the entire application to yourself. You do as well. At the very minimum, the console should run on a separate connection to the X server, or in its own thread on Windows. On OS X it won't ever work in the same process, unless, as you say, you modify PLGI. I think that the in-process console is a bad idea. Using pipes or network to communicate would easily let you have a remote console, etc.